# What is the best preserved Polynesian language?

Tags: polynesian-languages

From what I've heard, most of the polynesian languages aren't in good shape. For most native speakers are rare at best. Some, like Hawaiian have lost huge amounts of their vocabulary. I've read that its not possible to learn Hawaiian beyond a beginner level, because there is simply nothing else preserved of the language!

Are any of them in good shape? I'm not exactly an expert on the family. I've never really studied them much since, well, so much has been lost. I don't believe I could possibly get a taste for what the polynesian languages once were.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. My understanding is that the majority of the Polynesian languages are still pretty strong. Hawai'ian was perhaps the most endangered, but there is an island where it has continued to be spoken and elsewhere there is a strong revival movement. If you're keen, see the WP article on Polynesian languages and look each one up to find the numbers of speakers—Tahitian and Tongan each have many tens of thousands of speakers while Samoan has hundreds of thousands.

Comment: What do you mean by "best preserved"? Best-documented? Historically most archaic?

Comment: All the polynesian languages I know of have lost the vast majority of their vocabulary. Some grammatical features have also been lost, to the point that its impossible to say some things in certain polynesian languages.

Comment: Does Malagasy count? [18 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malagasy_language)

Comment: Malagasy isn't Polynesian. The speaker population information is available from Ethnologue, which recently started charging a fee for use, but has been free for several decades, so the numbers aren't secret. Most Polynesian languages are limited by population -- some of those islands are **small** -- and it's always been fairly normal for individual Austronesian languages to have smallish populations, often several on one island. The trick is to compare their utility with respect to invading languages like English or French.

Comment: [The Austronesian Languages](http://pacling.anu.edu.au/materials/Blust2013Austronesian.pdf) by Robert Blust (2013) lists ~50 Polynesian languages (p. 119) and gives speaker numbers for 20 of them, which range from >200,000 down to <1,000. It has a map of the Polynesian Triangle and provides a brief typological overview. If you want to learn a little of one of these languages there are online courses for a number of them. I'm sure you're right that some Polynesian languages no longer have speakers, and many are endangered, but the majority are still living languages and in daily use.